# Using .htaccess and .htpasswd gives empty pages

Tags: security, .htaccess, basic-authentication

I'm trying to password protect a webpage, say `index.html` that's located at `mysite.com/mysubfolder/index.html`. How I've done this, is I've placed both a `.htaccess` and a `.htpasswd` file in the directory `public_html/mysubfolder/`, with `.htacess` containing the following:

```
AuthName "Secure Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /public_html/mysubfolder/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Now, when I type in `www.mysite.com/mysubfolder` into the address bar, I get the prompt to type in the user name and password, which I do, with the credentials that generated my `.htpasswd` file. But when I do, an empty page shows up - no error or warning, just a white page. I have other folders inside this directory, and for them too nothing shows up, when I try to access them directly through the address bar. When I click `View Page Source`, all I see is

```
<!-- SHTML Wrapper - 500 Server Error -->
```

I have no idea what to do now. I want everyone who types in that webpage or clicks through a link to it (`mysite.com/mysubfolder/index.html` or `mysite.com/mysubfolder`)to have to type in the specific credentials I have chosen. Am I doing something wrong? Maybe there is a better way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems fine. Do you have an `index.shtml` file in that directory? If so, you might want to nuke it.... (And if there's no such file, maybe your web server is (mis)configured to do server-side includes handling for `.html` files.)

Comment: Nope, just index.html, a CSS stylesheet, jquery.js, the two .ht files, and three directories. Using Chrome on Mac OS 10.7.5. Also, only access to server is thorugh HostMoster control panel, but I'm not sure if it will let me control the stuff you mention.